# Simulataneous use of EntityManager and Session Manager

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a client who has an existing Hibernate JPA application.
For some of the optimization it would be beneficial to utilize stateless sessions.
I believe I should be able to use both the existing JPA EntityManager and also create a Hibernate Session Manager based StatelessSession.
The JPA would be used for the CRUD functionality, and the StatelessSession would implement bulk insert/updates.

I have not tried to use the two paradigms simultaneously before (always used either EntityManager or Hibernate sessions).

I think it should be possible to do fairly easily, but hopefully someone has done this and can warn me of any pitfalls.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about this:

```
Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
//session.persist(myEntity); Now you can use this session object for operations on entity
```

Entity manager exposes [getDelegate](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getDelegate%28%29) method to access underlying object which in hibernate case it is hibernate [Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html)

Comment: No that's not what I'm referring to. I'm actually talking about running two sessions simultaneously; one JPA and one native hibernate. What you're talking about would not give me a stateless session, which is what I need.

Comment: You are saying this: `I'm actually talking about running two sessions simultaneously; one JPA and one native hibernate`. This is not 2 session. this is one native hibernate session and 1 jpa netity manager. There is not such stateles or stateful session for hibernate session. the stateles or stateful session refeer to EJB beans which is very different from what Hibernate session is.

Comment: Ahh - no. Hibernate has what's called a StatelessSession. Here is the link if you would like to learn about it. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html

Comment: all right, I was thinking you are talking about ejb beans. i did not know that.